# Workflow for restricting document access in library

Tags: workflow

I'd like to create a document library for storing, say, exam papers. One group - Admin staff - should have full access and the other - Academics - should only have access to individual documents as required.

So, an academic visiting the library for the first time should see nothing - he should, however, be allowed to upload a document and then get full rights for that document. In addition, an admin staff member can grant him full rights for an existing document to collaborate on.

The main point here is that an academic CANNOT see any other documents unless explicitly granted.

So:

1. Can a custom permission level be created to allow upload ('Add Items'), but no read/view access (unless specified later for individual files)
2. Can a workflow then provide full rights to a document upon document upload? Which would then set 'No access' for all other academics in the group.

Many thanks

Neil

Comment: Which version of SP you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to create Custom Permission level for it, but instead you will have to apply item level permission here.

1. Create a WF which will run whenever a new document is uploaded to document library. This WF will have Replace List item permission
   step, which will assign full control permission to only the user who
   created the item and the **Admin Staff** group. This will assign
   item level permission to the document and others won't be able to
   see the document. Follow this [Post to create item level
   permission](http://spcycle.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html).
2. When the Admin staff wants to Share any document with any Academic
   user , they can assign permission to him OOTB or use
       "Share" feature if it is SP2013. Select document-->Click on Share
       button on ribbon.

Comment: Ah, so leave the library permissions as they are, but deny all other Academic users upon upload. Thanks (this is for SP2010)